# Batch - How to loop for all files which are the results of a command?

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I need to execute few command on the files which are the results of:

```
dir /S /b %Folder%\Production |grep %logfile% |grep -v Client
```

when:

```
set Folder=C:\someFolder
set date=2018-01-05
set logFile=platform.log.%date%
```

I tried:

```
for %%e in ('dir /S /b %Folder%\Production |grep %logfile% |grep -v Client') do ( 
    set logFullPath=%%e
    for /F "tokens=4 delims=\" %%a in (%logFullPath%) do set someName=%%a
    echo %logFullPath%
    echo %someName%
)
```

the nested for loop suppose to cut the file name with the full path (which is actually the 'dir' command output) to what comes between the third and the fourth "\" in the full path, for example:

```
C:\someFolder\Production\Application1\Logs\platform.log.2018-01-25
```

would become:

```
Application1
```

now, when trying to do all this, the moment the script reaches to the loop it shuts down.

I tried to do:

```
for /R %Folder%\Production %%e in (%logfile%*) do ( 
     echo %%e
     for /F "tokens=4 delims=\" %%a in (%%e) do echo %%a
)
```

And it worked with the first loop (although I wasn't able to exclude 'Client' liek with 'grep -v Client'), but for the nested loop it just printed "the system could not find the drive specified".

How am I suppose to do this when I have multiple commands to run on both loop outputs for each file that can be found by the 'dir' command, which is more than 1 file?

Comment: Why don't you shorten the command to `dir /S /b %Folder%\Production\%logfile% |grep -v Client` ?

Comment: It is not a good idea to modify Environment variables, like `set date=` rather create a new variable not used. like `set mydate=`

Comment: anyway, your magic needed here is `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and some other obvious changes to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is very likely because of your pipe characters inside the parentheses.

For that reason I would suggest escaping the **`|`** characters with carets, **`^`**:

```bat
('dir /S /b %Folder%\Production ^|grep %logfile% ^|grep -v Client')
```

Or surrounding the command with doublequotes to protect them:

```bat
('"dir /S /b %Folder%\Production |grep %logfile% |grep -v Client"')
```

Based on that and some of the other comments, then perhaps one of the following would work better for you.

With Delayed Expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Folder=C:\someFolder"
Set "myDate=2018-01-05"
Set "logFile=platform.log.%myDate%"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    Dir /B/S "%Folder%\Production\%logFile%"^|grep -v Client
') Do (Set "logFullPath=%%A"
    For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=\" %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "someName=%%B"
    Echo !logFullPath!
    Echo !someName!)
Pause
```

Without Delayed Expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "Folder=C:\someFolder"
Set "myDate=2018-01-05"
Set "logFile=platform.log.%myDate%"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    Dir /B/S "%Folder%\Production\%logfile%"^|grep -v Client
') Do (Set "logFullPath=%%A"
    For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=\" %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "someName=%%B"
    Call Echo %%logFullPath%%
    Call Echo %%someName%%)
Pause
```